# Why does including too big resources in my binary makes the compiler crash?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cl.exe

My goal is to generate a `*.dll` that contains all the resources the program needs (around 5 Mo worth of data). I use a program of my own that converts all the files in a folder into a big `.hpp` such as:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::map<std::string, std::vector<uint8_t>> assets {
{"file_A.md", {
    0x23, 0x20, 0x2A, 0x2A, 0x43, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x72, 0xC3, 0xB4, 0x6C, 0x65, 0x72, 0x20, 0x6C, 
    0x27, 0x61, 0x73, 0x70, 0x65, 0x63, 0x74, 0x20, 0x67, 0xC3, 0xA9, 0x6E, 0xC3, 0xA9, 0x72, 0x61}},
{"file_B.md", {
    0x24, 0x20, 0x2A, 0x2A, 0x43, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x72, 0xC3, 0xB4, 0x6C, 0x65, 0x72, 0x20, 0x6C, 
    0x27, 0x61, 0x73, 0x70, 0x65, 0x63, 0x74, 0x20, 0x67, 0xC3, 0xA9, 0x6E, 0xC3, 0xA9, 0x72, 0x61}},
...
...
};
```

Then I include this file into another project and use the map to iterate through the files.

When the size of the binaries converted are above around `500ko`, `mvsc 2019` (driven by `CMake`) crashes with the message :

```
[build] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6006: Arrêt de "CL.exe" avec le code -1073741571. [C:\GitHub\gtb-visual-control-template\build\gtb-visual-control-template.vcxproj]
[proc] The command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/GitHub/gtb-visual-control-template/build --config Debug --target ALL_BUILD -j 10 -- exited with code: 1
[build] Build finished with exit code 1
```

What could be the cause of the problem? Is it related to the type of structure I am using for holding the data ?

Comment: `-1073741571` is `0xC00000FD` which is stack overflow.  Compliers have limits you have probably exceeded one.  [MSVC Compiler Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/compiler-limits?view=msvc-170).

Comment: That's not going to work, too much data.  Store data in files, you can embed them in the DLL with the resource editor.  There's still a limit, a module can't be larger than 2GB.

Comment: Forcing this into an STL-style container is a problem. It requires dynamic allocation. With globals, they further require the data to init them already present, so you just make a copy of data already present. Changing that wouldn't fix your problem though. Maybe (not sure), it would allow you to split this into multiple files though, so that each file remains below the compiler's limits in size.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you use list initialization syntax (curly braces) to initialize an object that has a real constructor in it, that constructor call has to take an `initializer_list`. That `initializer_list` object points to an array of values which must exist somewhere. And that "somewhere" tends to be on a stack at some point.

So you need to make sure that the braced-init-list does not have so many values that it won't fit onto the stack.

So instead of directly initializing the `map` with that much data, you need to initialize a static C++ array type, and then use that to initialize the `map`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Nicol Bolas, I came up to this:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

constexpr uint8_t res_0[9]{
    0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 
};
constexpr uint8_t res_1[52]{
    0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6A, 0x6B, 0x6C, 0x6D, 0x6E, 0x6F, 0x70, 
    0x51, 0x52, 0x53, 0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57, 0x4B, 0x44, 0x4E, 0x45, 0x48, 0x48, 0x45, 0x48, 0x53, 
    0x48, 0x48, 0x53, 0x48, 0x53, 0x48, 0x53, 0x53, 0x48, 0x53, 0x48, 0x53, 0x48, 0x53, 0x4F, 0x4F, 
    0x5A, 0x4F, 0x4F, 0x5A, 
};

std::map<std::string, std::vector<uint8_t>> res {
{"abc.txt", {res_0[0], 9}},
{"def.txt", {res_1[0], 52}},
};
```

And it works like a charm. Just tried with 20Mo without any issue! I may share the conversion software that takes a folder as input and generates this header if some people want it.

Comment: An optimization would be not to use vector as mapped type but e.g. std::span<const unit8_t>. Less copying and memory allocation needs to take place then. Extra is to circumvent use of std::map and make it a constexpr completely.

Comment: @gast128 maybe a `std::vector<std::pair<const std::string,std::span<const unit8_t>>>`

Comment: ...or something like constexpr std::pair<const char*, std::span<const unit8_t>> g_a[] = {...}; I think one can even check if it is sorted at compile time with is_sorted and static_assert.